# Active users and views in azure workbooks

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-analysis-services, azure-dashboard, azure-monitor-workbooks

Can someone briefly explain the differences between active users and page views in an azure workbook? I would like to get the stats of active users of a particular azure event, but the counts shown are not realistic for the provided scenario.

[image]

As per the attached image, there is only one active user, which has to be at least 3-4 and can go up to 15-16. The value displayed in `Views` is unrealistic though.

Your valuable inputs are highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you edit the template/workbook and look at the queries you can see exactly what is going on there:

```
let start = startofday(ago({Metric}));
union customEvents, pageViews
| where timestamp >= start
| where name in ({Activities}) or '*' in ({Activities}) or ('%' in ({Activities}) and itemType == 'pageView') or ('#' in ({Activities}) and itemType == 'customEvent')
{OtherFilters}
| summarize Users = dcount(user_Id), Sessions = dcount(session_Id), Views = count()
| evaluate narrow()
| project Title = case(Column == 'Users', 'Active Users', Column == 'Sessions', 'Unique Sessions', 'Views'), Metric = Value, SubTitle = '━━'
```

views in this case, is a count of items in the tables; Views = `count()`,
Users is `dcount(user_Id)` and Sessions = `dcount(session_Id)`

seeing just 1 user/session implies that there's nothing automatically generating "distinct" ids for those values, so the user_Id, session_Id fields are completely empty across all rows (the one unique id being `undefined` in both columns)

how user and session id values get populated is very specific to what application insights sdks you are using, and how you've configured them.